# c++ cli hexadecimal editor works but is really slow

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, file-io, c++-cli, hex

I was trying to build a hexadecimal editor in c++ cli and got it to read binary files to a richtext box and the write binary files from the rich text box to an empty file. it works fine but is so slow for reading and especially for writing. could someone tell me how to fix this code or a better way of doing this all together.

yes I know that the 256 if statements will slow down the writing but I cant figure out how to convert the data system::string to write it out.

the writer takes like 2 minutes to write 50kb and the reader take like 10 seconds to read 50kb. I think this is really slow

thanks

Reader

```
if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {

             richTextBox1->Text = "";

                 String^ datafile = openFileDialog1->FileName;

FileStream fs(datafile, FileMode::Open);

BinaryReader br(%fs);

String^ data;
String^ datatotal;

double progressBar1count = 0;
double length = fs.Length;

progressBar1->Maximum = 100;

unsigned char byte;



for (__int64 count = 0, count_max = fs.Length; count < count_max; ++count)

{

  byte = br.ReadByte();

  data = byte.ToString(L"x2");

  datatotal = datatotal + data;

  Application::DoEvents();

  progressBar1count += 1;

  progressBar1->Value = progressBar1count / length * 100;

             }

datatotal = datatotal->ToUpper();

richTextBox1->Text = datatotal;

                 }

             progressBar1->Value = 0;
```

writer

```
if (saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {

    String^ datafile = saveFileDialog1->FileName;

String^ data = richTextBox1->Text;
double length = data->Length;

progressBar1->Maximum = 100;

int count = 0;
double countlength = 0;

string databasicstring;

fstream f(
    "C:\\users\\patchvista2\\b.exe",
    ios::out | ios::binary
    );

while (countlength < length - 1)

{

    String^ data = richTextBox1->Text;

    f.seekp(count, ios::beg );

    data = data->Substring(countlength , 2);

    count += 1;

  countlength += 2;

  progressBar1->Value = countlength / length * 100;

if (data == "00") {
     f.put(0x00);    
}

if (data == "01") {
     f.put(0x01);
}

if (data == "02") {
     f.put(0x02);
}

if (data == "03") {
     f.put(0x03);
}

if (data == "04") {
     f.put(0x04);
}

if (data == "05") {
    f.put(0x05);
}

if (data == "06") {
    f.put(0x06);
}

if (data == "07") {
    f.put(0x07);
}

if (data == "08") {
    f.put(0x08);
}

if (data == "09") {
    f.put(0x09);
}

if (data == "0A") {
    f.put(0x0A);
}

if (data == "0B") {
    f.put(0x0B);
}

if (data == "0C") {
    f.put(0x0C);
}

if (data == "0D") {
    f.put(0x0D);
}

if (data == "0E") {
    f.put(0x0E);
}

if (data == "0F") {
    f.put(0x0F);
}

if (data == "10") {
    f.put(0x10);
}

if (data == "11") {
    f.put(0x11);
}

if (data == "12") {
    f.put(0x12);
}

if (data == "13") {
    f.put(0x13);
}

if (data == "14") {
    f.put(0x14);
}

if (data == "15") {
    f.put(0x15);
}

if (data == "16") {
    f.put(0x16);
}

if (data == "17") {
    f.put(0x17);
}

if (data == "18") {
    f.put(0x18);
}

if (data == "19") {
    f.put(0x19);
}

if (data == "1A") {
    f.put(0x1A);
}

if (data == "1B") {
    f.put(0x1B);
}

if (data == "1C") {
    f.put(0x1C);
}

if (data == "1D") {
    f.put(0x1D);
}

if (data == "1E") {
    f.put(0x1E);
}

if (data == "1F") {
    f.put(0x1F);
}

if (data == "20") {
    f.put(0x20);
}

if (data == "21") {
    f.put(0x21);
}

if (data == "22") {
    f.put(0x22);
}

if (data == "23") {
    f.put(0x23);
}

if (data == "24") {
    f.put(0x24);
}

if (data == "25") {
    f.put(0x25);
}

if (data == "26") {
    f.put(0x26);
}

if (data == "27") {
    f.put(0x27);
}

if (data == "28") {
    f.put(0x28);
}

if (data == "29") {
    f.put(0x29);
}

if (data == "2A") {
    f.put(0x2A);
}

if (data == "2B") {
    f.put(0x2B);
}

if (data == "2C") {
    f.put(0x2C);
}

if (data == "2D") {
    f.put(0x2D);
}

if (data == "2E") {
    f.put(0x2E);
}

if (data == "2F") {
    f.put(0x2F);
}

if (data == "30") {
    f.put(0x30);
}

if (data == "31") {
    f.put(0x31);
}

if (data == "32") {
    f.put(0x32);
}

if (data == "33") {
    f.put(0x33);
}

if (data == "34") {
    f.put(0x34);
}

if (data == "35") {
    f.put(0x35);
}

if (data == "36") {
    f.put(0x36);
}

if (data == "37") {
    f.put(0x37);
}

if (data == "38") {
    f.put(0x38);
}

if (data == "39") {
    f.put(0x39);
}

if (data == "3A") {
    f.put(0x3A);
}

if (data == "3B") {
    f.put(0x3B);
}

if (data == "3C") {
    f.put(0x3C);
}

if (data == "3D") {
    f.put(0x3D);
}

if (data == "3E") {
    f.put(0x3E);
}

if (data == "3F") {
    f.put(0x3F);
}

if (data == "40") {
    f.put(0x40);
}

if (data == "41") {
    f.put(0x41);
}

if (data == "42") {
    f.put(0x42);
}

if (data == "43") {
    f.put(0x43);
}

if (data == "44") {
    f.put(0x44);
}

if (data == "45") {
    f.put(0x45);
}

if (data == "46") {
    f.put(0x46);
}

if (data == "47") {
    f.put(0x47);
}

if (data == "48") {
    f.put(0x48);
}

if (data == "49") {
    f.put(0x49);
}

if (data == "4A") {
    f.put(0x4A);
}

if (data == "4B") {
    f.put(0x4B);
}

if (data == "4C") {
    f.put(0x4C);
}

if (data == "4D") {
    f.put(0x4D);
}

if (data == "4E") {
    f.put(0x4E);
}

if (data == "4F") {
    f.put(0x4F);
}

if (data == "50") {
    f.put(0x50);
}

if (data == "51") {
    f.put(0x51);
}

if (data == "52") {
    f.put(0x52);
}

if (data == "53") {
    f.put(0x53);
}

if (data == "54") {
    f.put(0x54);
}

if (data == "55") {
    f.put(0x55);
}

if (data == "56") {
    f.put(0x56);
}

if (data == "57") {
    f.put(0x57);
}

if (data == "58") {
    f.put(0x58);
}

if (data == "59") {
    f.put(0x59);
}

if (data == "5A") {
    f.put(0x5A);
}

if (data == "5B") {
    f.put(0x5B);
}

if (data == "5C") {
    f.put(0x5C);
}

if (data == "5D") {
    f.put(0x5D);
}

if (data == "5E") {
    f.put(0x5E);
}

if (data == "5F") {
    f.put(0x5F);
}

if (data == "60") {
    f.put(0x60);
}

if (data == "61") {
    f.put(0x61);
}

if (data == "62") {
    f.put(0x62);
}

if (data == "63") {
    f.put(0x63);
}

if (data == "64") {
    f.put(0x64);
}

if (data == "65") {
    f.put(0x65);
}

if (data == "66") {
    f.put(0x66);
}

if (data == "67") {
    f.put(0x67);
}

if (data == "68") {
    f.put(0x68);
}

if (data == "69") {
    f.put(0x69);
}

if (data == "6A") {
    f.put(0x6A);
}

if (data == "6B") {
    f.put(0x6B);
}

if (data == "6C") {
    f.put(0x6C);
}

if (data == "6D") {
    f.put(0x6D);
}

if (data == "6E") {
    f.put(0x6E);
}

if (data == "6F") {
    f.put(0x6F);
}

if (data == "70") {
    f.put(0x70);
}

if (data == "71") {
    f.put(0x71);
}

if (data == "72") {
    f.put(0x72);
}

if (data == "73") {
    f.put(0x73);
}

if (data == "74") {
    f.put(0x74);
}

if (data == "75") {
    f.put(0x75);
}

if (data == "76") {
    f.put(0x76);
}

if (data == "77") {
    f.put(0x77);
}

if (data == "78") {
    f.put(0x78);
}

if (data == "79") {
    f.put(0x79);
}

if (data == "7A") {
    f.put(0x7A);
}

if (data == "7B") {
    f.put(0x7B);
}

if (data == "7C") {
    f.put(0x7C);
}

if (data == "7D") {
    f.put(0x7D);
}

if (data == "7E") {
    f.put(0x7E);
}

if (data == "7F") {
    f.put(0x7F);
}

if (data == "80") {
    f.put(0x80);
}

if (data == "81") {
    f.put(0x81);
}

if (data == "82") {
    f.put(0x82);
}

if (data == "83") {
    f.put(0x83);
}

if (data == "84") {
    f.put(0x84);
}

if (data == "85") {
    f.put(0x85);
}

if (data == "86") {
    f.put(0x86);
}

if (data == "87") {
    f.put(0x87);
}

if (data == "88") {
    f.put(0x88);
}

if (data == "89") {
    f.put(0x89);
}

if (data == "8A") {
    f.put(0x8A);
}

if (data == "8B") {
    f.put(0x8B);
}

if (data == "8C") {
    f.put(0x8C);
}

if (data == "8D") {
    f.put(0x8D);
}

if (data == "8E") {
    f.put(0x8E);
}

if (data == "8F") {
    f.put(0x8F);
}

if (data == "90") {
    f.put(0x90);
}

if (data == "91") {
    f.put(0x91);
}

if (data == "92") {
    f.put(0x92);
}

if (data == "93") {
    f.put(0x93);
}

if (data == "94") {
    f.put(0x94);
}

if (data == "95") {
    f.put(0x95);
}

if (data == "96") {
    f.put(0x96);
}

if (data == "97") {
    f.put(0x97);
}

if (data == "98") {
    f.put(0x98);
}

if (data == "99") {
    f.put(0x99);
}

if (data == "9A") {
    f.put(0x9A);
}

if (data == "9B") {
    f.put(0x9B);
}

if (data == "9C") {
    f.put(0x9C);
}

if (data == "9D") {
    f.put(0x9D);
}

if (data == "9E") {
    f.put(0x9E);
}

if (data == "9F") {
    f.put(0x9F);
}

if (data == "A0") {
    f.put(0xA0);
}

if (data == "A1") {
    f.put(0xA1);
}

if (data == "A2") {
    f.put(0xA2);
}

if (data == "A3") {
    f.put(0xA3);
}

if (data == "A4") {
    f.put(0xA4);
}

if (data == "A5") {
    f.put(0xA5);
}

if (data == "A6") {
    f.put(0xA6);
}

if (data == "A7") {
    f.put(0xA7);
}

if (data == "A8") {
    f.put(0xA8);
}

if (data == "A9") {
    f.put(0xA9);
}

if (data == "AA") {
    f.put(0xAA);
}

if (data == "AB") {
    f.put(0xAB);
}

if (data == "AC") {
    f.put(0xAC);
}

if (data == "AD") {
    f.put(0xAD);
}

if (data == "AE") {
    f.put(0xAE);
}

if (data == "AF") {
    f.put(0xAF);
}

if (data == "B0") {
    f.put(0xB0);
}

if (data == "B1") {
    f.put(0xB1);
}

if (data == "B2") {
    f.put(0xB2);
}

if (data == "B3") {
    f.put(0xB3);
}

if (data == "B4") {
    f.put(0xB4);
}

if (data == "B5") {
    f.put(0xB5);
}

if (data == "B6") {
    f.put(0xB6);
}

if (data == "B7") {
    f.put(0xB7);
}

if (data == "B8") {
    f.put(0xB8);
}

if (data == "B9") {
    f.put(0xB9);
}

if (data == "BA") {
    f.put(0xBA);
}

if (data == "BB") {
    f.put(0xBB);
}

if (data == "BC") {
    f.put(0xBC);
}

if (data == "BD") {
    f.put(0xBD);
}

if (data == "BE") {
    f.put(0xBE);
}

if (data == "BF") {
    f.put(0xBF);
}

if (data == "C0") {
    f.put(0xC0);
}

if (data == "C1") {
    f.put(0xC1);
}

if (data == "C2") {
    f.put(0xC2);
}

if (data == "C3") {
    f.put(0xC3);
}

if (data == "C4") {
    f.put(0xC4);
}

if (data == "C5") {
    f.put(0xC5);
}

if (data == "C6") {
    f.put(0xC6);
}

if (data == "C7") {
    f.put(0xC7);
}

if (data == "C8") {
    f.put(0xC8);
}

if (data == "C9") {
    f.put(0xC9);
}

if (data == "CA") {
    f.put(0xCA);
}

if (data == "CB") {
    f.put(0xCB);
}

if (data == "CC") {
    f.put(0xCC);
}

if (data == "CD") {
    f.put(0xCD);
}

if (data == "CE") {
    f.put(0xCE);
}

if (data == "CF") {
    f.put(0xCF);
}

if (data == "D0") {
    f.put(0xD0);
}

if (data == "D1") {
    f.put(0xD1);
}

if (data == "D2") {
    f.put(0xD2);
}

if (data == "D3") {
    f.put(0xD3);
}

if (data == "D4") {
    f.put(0xD4);
}

if (data == "D5") {
    f.put(0xD5);
}

if (data == "D6") {
    f.put(0xD6);
}

if (data == "D7") {
    f.put(0xD7);
}

if (data == "D8") {
    f.put(0xD8);
}

if (data == "D9") {
    f.put(0xD9);
}

if (data == "DA") {
    f.put(0xDA);
}

if (data == "DB") {
    f.put(0xDB);
}

if (data == "DC") {
    f.put(0xDC);
}

if (data == "DD") {
    f.put(0xDD);
}

if (data == "DE") {
    f.put(0xDE);
}

if (data == "DF") {
    f.put(0xDF);
}

if (data == "E0") {
    f.put(0xE0);
}

if (data == "E1") {
    f.put(0xE1);
}

if (data == "E2") {
    f.put(0xE2);
}

if (data == "E3") {
    f.put(0xE3);
}

if (data == "E4") {
    f.put(0xE4);
}

if (data == "E5") {
    f.put(0xE5);
}

if (data == "E6") {
    f.put(0xE6);
}

if (data == "E7") {
    f.put(0xE7);
}

if (data == "E8") {
    f.put(0xE8);
}

if (data == "E9") {
    f.put(0xE9);
}

if (data == "EA") {
    f.put(0xEA);
}

if (data == "EB") {
    f.put(0xEB);
}

if (data == "EC") {
    f.put(0xEC);
}

if (data == "ED") {
    f.put(0xED);
}

if (data == "EE") {
    f.put(0xEE);
}

if (data == "EF") {
    f.put(0xEF);
}

if (data == "F0") {
    f.put(0xF0);
}

if (data == "F1") {
    f.put(0xF1);
}

if (data == "F2") {
    f.put(0xF2);
}

if (data == "F3") {
    f.put(0xF3);
}

if (data == "F4") {
    f.put(0xF4);
}

if (data == "F5") {
    f.put(0xF5);
}

if (data == "F6") {
    f.put(0xF6);
}

if (data == "F7") {
    f.put(0xF7);
}

if (data == "F8") {
    f.put(0xF8);
}

if (data == "F9") {
    f.put(0xF9);
}

if (data == "FA") {
    f.put(0xFA);
}

if (data == "FB") {
    f.put(0xFB);
}

if (data == "FC") {
    f.put(0xFC);
}

if (data == "FD") {
    f.put(0xFD);
}

if (data == "FE") {
    f.put(0xFE);
}

if (data == "FF") {
    f.put(0xFF);
}



}

f.close();

progressBar1->Value = 0;

MessageBox::Show("done saving the file");

}
```

Comment: Stop updating the UI for every single byte that you read/write.  You also must remove DoEvents from this code.  That will stop the UI from updating but that doesn't matter anymore since the code should not take more than a fraction of a second.  Move the code into a BackgroundWorker for big files.

Comment: how do i use a background worker. I looked at msdn and it is really confusing and how do i stop the screen from updating I took out the do events and it is still slow. I saw their is WM_SETREDRAW but I don't know how to use it in c++ cli. in assembly I can just go invoke and the the command with the parameters

Comment: You have a lot to learn, all covered in other SO questions, don't try to do this all in one big gulp.  The code you have now completely sucks mud so fix that first.  Solves the problem for small amounts of text.  That gives you plenty of time to learn the ropes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Writer

First of all, you save time if you do not assign `String^ data = richTextBox1->Text;` at the beginning of every iteration of your loop on the writer side. Instead, why don't you declare another variable (`temp`) and keep `data` the same to reduce assignment operations? For example:

```
String temp;
temp = data->Substring(countlength , 2);
```

You can then effectively remove `data = data->Substring(countlength , 2);` from the beginning of your loop inside the writer routine.

Secondly, familiarize yourself with [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). This function can effectively convert an string (`char *`) to an integer of any base. For example:

```
char * string = "0f";
int num = strtol(string, NULL, 16); //Using base 16 (hex)
```

`num` int this case will be `15` or `0x0F`in hex. This will essentially replace your `if`statement pile.

#### Reader

Reduce calls to `Application::DoEvents();` as this is too costly if you do not need to repaint every time you read a byte in. Instead, repaint in 10% intervals for example. Another costly call you make every iteration is `progressBar1->Value = progressBar1count / length * 100;` however this is also related to the whole repainting concept. In other words,  **update your GUI at a more resonable interval than every byte**.

*EDIT 1: Changed `strtol(s, NULL, 16)` to `strtol(string, NULL, 16)`

EDIT 2: Separated answer into Reader/Writer segments.*

Comment: thank you for the tempdata it now writes a lot faster. I tried the strtol stuff but now i get an your exe hash crashed thing now when i write and the resulting exe is 0b this is what i tried, I removed the 256 if statements and replaced them with this code string hexadecimaltemp;

  MarshalString(datatemp,hexadecimaltemp);
   const size_t newsize = 2;
    char nstring[newsize];
    strcpy_s(nstring, hexadecimaltemp.c_str());
    strcat_s(nstring, " (char *)");

  int hexadecimal = strtol(nstring, NULL, 16);
  f.put(hexadecimal);      datatemp is the substring 2 system::string

Comment: also do you have any suggestions for the reading section. thanks

Comment: nevermind I got it to work using this code const char* text = (const char*)(void*)
       Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(datatemp);
int hexadecimal = strtol(text, NULL, 16); //Using base 16 (hex)
    
f.put(hexadecimal);  thank you so much Phil for getting the writer to write fast. I do however still need help for the reader part of this code if Phil or anyone can help. the reader is still slow

Comment: @patchariadog - I'm assuming `Application::DoEvents();` is for repainting and is necessary? You could consider reading more bytes at a time before you make this repaint call.